# Вызов приложения

Tags: django

Я новичок в Django.

Необходимо вызвать приложение для отрисовки  меню. Вызывается именно такой командой:

```
{% draw_menu 'main_menu' %}
```

Что это? Что это строка из себя представляет? Не понятно скорее что означает строка в кавычках. Это параметр команды draw_menu? Как я понял, к шаблонам это не относится.

Comment: Это тег для шаблона. Скорее всего предыдущий программист сделал свой.

Answer (score 0):

Это template tag дока тут [template-tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/)

примерно выглядит вот так

```
 apps/
   app_name/
     templatetags/
        __init__.py
        template_tags.py

        @register.simple_tag
        def draw_menu(type)
            template = '{template_name}.html'.format(template_name=type)
            context = {}
            return render_to_string(template, context)
```